# Bootstap Vue.js: best practice for supplementing link text with the title attribute for <b-nav-item>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, wcag

I'm using Bootstrap Vue.js to implement navigation and I'm wondering what is the best practice to set an anchor title for `<b-nav-item>`. I would like to do this in order to cover one of the WCAG techniques (https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H33)

```
<b-nav>
   <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'global', query: this.$route.query }" exact-active-class="active" exact
      title="Global">
      <span>Global</span>
   </b-nav-item>
   <b-nav-item
      :to="{ name: 'stats-index-cars', query: this.$route.query }"
      v-if="$can('viewGroupedByCar', 'reports')"
      exact-active-class="active"
      exact
      <span>{{this.$store.module_names.CAR}}s</span>
   </b-nav-item>
</b-nav>
```

Comment: I've seen examples with the `title` on the <b-nav-item> itself, but when I tried that, it generates code with the title on the <li> instead of on the <a>, which is not what you want.

Comment: It looks like <b-nav-item> supports [`link-attrs`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/nav#__BVID__412__row_link-attrs), *"Additional attributes to place on the nested link element"*, so you should be able to specify your title in there.